# Updating Post not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I recently made a code that updates my posts on my blog. It worked perfectly on localhost. But when i uploaded it online it did not work any more. The weird thing is it doesn't even display a error so i have no idea where to look. Can someone please help me ?

```
require('config.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM project ORDER BY idproject DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($verbinding, $query ) or die (mysqli_error('kan geen verbinding maken met de database'));
if(isset($_POST['editBut'])){
    $editTitle = $_POST['editName'];
    $editThis = mysqli_query($verbinding, "SELECT * FROM project WHERE title = '".$editTitle."'");
    $values = mysqli_fetch_assoc($editThis);
}
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $editedTitle = $_POST['newTitle'];
    $editedText = $_POST['newTekst'];
    $oldTitle = $_POST['oldTitle'];
    $date = $_POST['datum'];
    $updater = mysqli_query($verbinding, "UPDATE Project SET title='".$editedTitle."', content='".$editedText."' WHERE title='".$oldTitle."' AND datum='".$date."'");
    echo $updater;
    header('location:editPost.php?id=1');
}
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    echo 'post has been succesfully updated';
}

<?php if(isset($_POST['editBut'])){ ?>
            <form action="" method="post">
                Title: <input type="text" name="newTitle" value="<?php echo $values['title'] ?>"><br>
                Text: <textarea type="text" name="newTekst" id="newTekst"><?php echo $values['content'] ?></textarea><br>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $values['title'] ?>" name="oldTitle">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $values['datum'] ?>" name="datum">
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Edit post">
            </form>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <p>Find the post you want to edit:</p>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <select name="editName">
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                       ?> <option value="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="editBut" value="Choose">
            </form>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: is only update not working ???

Comment: Your webpage is not displaying the errors because of security reasons. It is likely to be turned `off`. To enable it add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the top of your page (JUST for testing purposes). **Do not forget to remove it after you have found the error !!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In update query replace your table name with small letter.

replace `Project` with `project`